# Tokenizing file input and storing data in struct

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is to read input from file which is in the format of `Data1;Data2;Data3;Data4;Data5` I want to tokenize this string, and store each of these separate pieces of information in a structure such as;

```
struct example {
    char data1[10];
    char data2[10];
    char data3[10];
    char data4[10];
    char data5[10];
};
```

Here's what I have for my input function so far:

```
void userInput() { // I will need to change return type
    FILE *file;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    struct example data[5];

    file = fopen(DATA, "r");

    if(file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening data file.\n");
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file) != null) {
        //tokenize strings, and add to struct here
    }
}
```

I realize that in my while function I will need something like:

```
....
char *token = NULL;
token = strtok(string, ";");

while(token != NULL) {
    // add to struct here
    token = strtok(NULL, ";");
}
```

Could someone explain how I would loop through my struct to add this? Or if I'm even going about this the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a struct, you need some sort of counter to differentiate between your structure elements.  Something like:

```
int x = 0;
while(token != NULL) {

    token = strtok(NULL, ";");

    // add to struct here

    if (x == 0){
        data1 = token;
    }else if (x == 1){
        data2 = token;
    }else if (...)
    // ... keep going

    x++;
}
```

Comment: I figured this is the way I was going to go with it, but it doesn't seem that clean. Thanks though!

Comment: I agree.  We'll see if anyone has a more elegant solution.  The other answer is right in that you should use strcpy instead of directly assigning from a char array.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things you want to iterate over. I assume each line of input corresponds to a different `struct example`. Then, you want to iterate over each field in your structure. You need a counter to iterate over your `data` array, and then you need a mechanism to iterate over the fields. I would use a temporary array to accomplish that:

```
int i = 0;
while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file) != null && i < 5) {
    char *fields[] = {
        data[i].data1, data[i].data2, data[i].data3,
        data[i].data4, data[i].data5
    };
    size_t lengths[] = {
        sizeof(data[i].data1), sizeof(data[i].data2), sizeof(data[i].data3),
        sizeof(data[i].data4), sizeof(data[i].data5)
    };
    char *token = NULL;
    int j = 0;
    token = strtok(string, ";");
    while(token != NULL && j < 5) {
        snprintf(fields[j], lengths[j], "%s", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ";");
        ++j;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: You need to watch for j going out of bounds.